# Quasar exception on fetching node identity information in Corda Flow tests

Tags: corda

I have flow tests that execute flow logic to generate new party and certificates using the (test) key management service. At setup, I create a mock network instance along with multiple `StartedMockNode` instances. Our project is written in Kotlin 1.1.60, uses corda-3.3 open source (OS), running on JDK 1.8_u192. On running the tests in IntelliJ Idea 2019.3, I get the following exception from the quasar library.

```
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2217) ~[guava-21.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4154) ~[guava-21.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:5060) ~[guava-21.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.NonInvalidatingCache.get(NonInvalidatingCache.kt) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AppendOnlyPersistentMapBase.set(AppendOnlyPersistentMap.kt:53) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AppendOnlyPersistentMapBase.addWithDuplicatesAllowed(AppendOnlyPersistentMap.kt:100) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AppendOnlyPersistentMapBase.addWithDuplicatesAllowed$default(AppendOnlyPersistentMap.kt:99) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.identity.PersistentIdentityService.verifyAndRegisterIdentity(PersistentIdentityService.kt:139) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.api.IdentityServiceInternal$DefaultImpls.justVerifyAndRegisterIdentity(IdentityServiceInternal.kt:9) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.identity.PersistentIdentityService.justVerifyAndRegisterIdentity(PersistentIdentityService.kt:31) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.keys.KMSUtilsKt.freshCertificate(KMSUtils.kt:50) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.keys.E2ETestKeyManagementService.freshKeyAndCert(E2ETestKeyManagementService.kt:56) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Was expecting to find transaction set on current strand: Fiber@10000001:[9b1b68cc-578e-479d-8584-6376c1f3bb89][task: co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask@496179b9(Fiber@10000001), target: null, scheduler: net.corda.node.services.statemachine.StateMachineManagerImpl$FiberScheduler@7d174b11]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.DatabaseTransactionKt.getContextTransaction(DatabaseTransaction.kt:14) ~[corda-node-api-3.3-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.DatabaseTransactionKt.currentDBSession(DatabaseTransaction.kt:9) ~[corda-node-api-3.3-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AppendOnlyPersistentMapBase$addWithDuplicatesAllowed$1.invoke(AppendOnlyPersistentMap.kt:101) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AppendOnlyPersistentMapBase$set$existingInCache$1.call(AppendOnlyPersistentMap.kt:58) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AppendOnlyPersistentMapBase$set$existingInCache$1.call(AppendOnlyPersistentMap.kt:15) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:5065) ~[guava-21.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3716) ~[guava-21.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2424) ~[guava-21.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2298) ~[guava-21.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2211) ~[guava-21.0.jar:?]
    ... 27 more
```

My code did not have any significant deviation in flow or test logic from the recommended approaches in corda documentation. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Switching IntelliJ settings appears to address this issue. On updating the test settings in 'Preferences' -> 'Build, Execution, Deployment' -> 'Gradle' -> 'Build and run using' to 'Gradle' instead of 'IntelliJ Idea', and just below that 'Run tests using' to 'Gradle' instead of 'IntelliJ Idea', the flow tests ran successfully as expected. No other change was required.

[image: IntelliJ Idea Screenshot]